# arcpy get database path of feature class in feature dataset

Tags: python, database, path, dataset, arcpy

I am trying to get the database path of a feature class that may or may not be in a feature dataset. I am using the `os.path.dirname` of the feature class. This will give me either the database path if the feature class is not in a feature dataset (great), but if the feature class is in a feature dataset, it will give me the path to the feature dataset.

This could be a file, personal or sde geodatabase. I was thinking of a `split` using the '.sde' but that won't work if it is a different type of geodatabase.

A sample of the path could be:

- For inside a feature dataset: **C:\GISData\Data.gdb\Property\Erf**
- For under the gdb root: **C:\GISData\Data.gdb\Erf**

In both these cases I would like to get **C:\GISData\Data.gdb**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out this short [blog posting](http://www.gispd.com/blog/?p=551) which they use the following function:

```
def get_geodatabase_path(input_table):
  '''Return the Geodatabase path from the input table or feature class.
  :param input_table: path to the input table or feature class 
  '''
  workspace = os.path.dirname(input_table)
  if [any(ext) for ext in ('.gdb', '.mdb', '.sde') if ext in os.path.splitext(workspace)]:
    return workspace
  else:
    return os.path.dirname(workspace)
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This helped a great deal. I managed to get something working through some `try` and `except` checking the `workspaceType` or `datasetType == "FeatureDataset"`, but this is definitely a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Also see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112288/how-to-set-workspace-from-input-feature-class for handling Feature Datasets in path

Answer (score 6):

Another way which is not obvious from the documentation is to use the **path** (Read Only) property:

[Describe object properties](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/describe-object-properties.htm)

```
import arcpy
desc = arcpy.Describe(r"C:\GISData\Data.gdb\Erf")
print desc.path

# prints: u"C:\\GISData\\Data.gdb"
```

Comment: (I assumed you were using arcpy)

Comment: This does not get around the problem of feature datasets within a geodatabase as they are reported by `path`. It is only a substitute for the `os.path.dirname` function.